# "Exception thrown: read access violation. this->head was nullptr."

Tags: c++

I'm writing code that removes every other element from a Linked List.  It works when there are enough elements in the List.  When there are not enough elements, I'm trying to still have the code run through a `while` loop for other options (add, remove, etc).  However, an error pops up

> Exception thrown: read access violation. this->head was nullptr.

How would I fix this? I provided the function below:

```
void removeEveryOtherNode() {
    Chunk* previous = head;
    Chunk* pointer = head->next; //error happens here

    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "Linked List is empty...Nothing to delete" << endl;
    }

    else if (pointer == NULL) {
        cout << "Not enough elements to delete every other element." << endl;
    }

    while (previous != NULL && pointer != NULL) {
        previous->next = pointer->next;
        delete pointer;
        previous = previous->next;
        if (previous != NULL) {
            pointer = previous->next;
        }
    }
    cout << "Removed every other element. Press 4 to display" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You're dereferencing `head` before checking if it's valid.

Comment: Is `head` a global variable?  Need you to post the definition of `head` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You should check if head is valid before dereferencing it

```
if (head == NULL) {
     cout << "Linked List is empty...Nothing to delete" << endl;
     return;
}
if (head->next == NULL) {
     cout << "Not enough elements to delete every other element." << endl;
     return;
}

// then dereference
Chunk* pointer = head->next;
```

Also, use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.